# SyntaxError: 'return' outside function(using jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

**SyntaxError: 'return' outside function, any solution for this? using jupyter notebook**

```
string='"hello"'
for i in string:
    if i=='\"':
      d=string.replace("\"","")
      return d
    else:
      return string
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when it hits the `return`? `return` is intended to return a value from a function. Perhaps you are looking for a [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break)?

Comment: "any solution for this?" - you could put the return inside a function.

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: I wanted to get the input statement from the user and just wanted to remove any double inverted in the statement, I wanted to return any one value( i.e statement without double inverted)

Comment: your code makes no sense - use directly single line `string = string.replace("\"","")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a return statement **must** be inside a function

for instance:

```
def my_function():
    string='"hello"'
    for i in string:
        if i=='\"':
          d=string.replace("\"","")
          return d
        else:
          return string
```

This solves and explains your error. furas comment says:

> "Your code makes no sense - use directly single line string =
> string.replace(""","") –  furas"

Comment: yeah i know this is the sample code made to ask question my code is complicated, so i posted the simple version of it